# How do I create a report in Excel marking empty cells as "n" and cells with any input as "y" for a range of cells?

Tags: vba, excel, report, formula

As an example, say I have five columns and five rows of data. Column A would all be names, where the remaining four columns, B through E, include user-generated data about each individual person.

I want to create a report whereby I can preserve the `name` column, but for the remaining columns, simply automate a "y" or "n" output depending on if the fields were left blank or not, essentially being Person A filled out this category, or didn't fill out another, etc.

Basically to turn this:

`[person a][populated cell][populated cell][blank cell][blank cell][populated cell]`

into:

`[person a][y][y][n][n][y]`

Is this possible just within Excel itself? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select the worksheet and run this macro:

```
Sub Yes_No()
    Dim RR As Range, N As Long
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Set RR = Range("B1:E" & N)
    For Each r In RR
        If r.Value = "" Then
            r.Value = "no"
        Else
            r.Value = "yes"
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

**EDIT#1**

To produce a report on a separate sheet, create a new worksheet called **Report,**  then select the original sheet and run this macro:

```
Sub Yes_No()
    Dim RR As Range, N As Long, rs As Worksheet, _
        ady As String
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Set RR = Range("B1:E" & N)
    Set rs = Sheets("Report")
    For Each r In RR
        ady = r.Address
        If r.Value = "" Then
            rs.Range(ady).Value = "no"
        Else
            rs.Range(ady).Value = "yes"
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! As a brief follow up, is there a way to do this as a separate report instead of editing the current sheet?

Comment: See **EDIT#1** ________________